# Trying to make Spotify widget responsive via jQuery but can't get it done. Help me

Tags: jquery, spotify

Something must be wrong with this code. It was suppose to resize the Spotify iframe this way:

---

if the parent div's width is more than 500px, then

width: parent div's width

height: parent div's width + 80px

---

or if the parent div's width is not more than 500px, then

width: parent div's width

height: 80px

---

```js
function(spotify) {
  var w = $(".audio-embed").width(),
    h = w + 80,
    s = spotify && spotify.length ? $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]', spotify) : $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]');
  s.each(w > 500 ? function() {
    $(this).css({
        width: w,
        height: h
      }),
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
  } : function() {
    $(this).css({
        width: w,
        height: 80
      }),
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
  });
});
```

```css
.audio-embed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.spotify_audio_player {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-embed">
  <iframe class="spotify_audio_player" src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify%3Atrack%3A4DfUmbnnxpRlwLsFYfmGfn&amp;view=coverart" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" width="500" height="580"></iframe>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`function (spotify) {
    var w = $(".audio-embed").width(),
        h = w + 80,
        s = spotify && spotify.length ? $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]', spotify) : $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]');
    s.each(w > 500 ? function () {
        $(this).css({
            width: w,
            height: h
        }),
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    } : function () {
        $(this).css({
            width: w,
            height: 80
        }),
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    });
});`

I know I'm not good with jQuery codes. I can't even figure out where it's gone wrong.

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: If i exists and i has a length attribute not==0, set o to iframe that has src with something.com in it in i's context, else set o to  iframe that has src with something.com in it  in current context

Comment: its a ternary operation same as if/else like `var a = condition ? if true : if false;`

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comments section:

```
var o = i && i.length ? $('iframe[src*="something.com"]', i) : $('iframe[src*="something.com"]');
```

here `var o` will be assigned an object if this condition is true/false

```
i && i.length
```

if it results in a boolean `true` then this iframe jquery object with a specific `src` in the context of `i` will be assigned to `var o`:

```
$('iframe[src*="something.com"]', i) // find iframe with specific src in "i"
                                     // where i could be document or parent
                                     // of the iframe.
```

the above selector could also be written like this:

```
$(i).find('iframe[src*="something.com"]') // works same as above.
```

otherwise if condition results in `false` then this iframe jquery object with a specific `src` will be assigned:

```
$('iframe[src*="something.com"]')
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you please take a look now? @Jai

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially a ternary conditional. This is the syntax:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

You can read more about them here: [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Breaking it down, the condition in this case is `i && i.length`. This means does the variable `i` contain a truthy value ([what's that?](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/javascript-conventions/what-are-truthy-and-falsy-values)) and is its length greater than zero. This is a typical way to check if an element exists on a page using jQuery.

If it is, then the variable `o` is set to reference the iframe with a src attribute containing the given substring of "something.com" in the context of `i`. I believe this is the same as saying `i.find($('iframe[src*="something.com"]'));`.

If the above condition is false, then o is assigned a reference to the iframe with a src attribute containing the given substring of "something.com"

Answer (score -1):

```
(function(i) {
```

There is likely a bit more code on this line that runs the anonymous function. that is declared with function(i) {. Anonymous functions have no set identifier, although you can assign them to a variable.

The next line is fairly complex so I will attempt to break it down:

```
var o = i
```

Assigns i to 0.

```
&&
```

If o evaluates to true, the next section of the line executes, if it evaluates to false it doesn't. This happens because javascript is a dynamic typed language.

```
i.length ? *true* : *false*;
```

The next part is a ternary operator. If i.length evalues to true (likely  when i.length doesn't equal 0), then *true* executes, if not *false* executes.

```
$('iframe[src*="something.com"]', i) and $('iframe[src*="something.com"]');
```

The last part is a jQuery selector, the first uses i as it's context, the second one uses the default context (I believe it is the whole webpage, or html). The context defines where jQuery looks for the element.